# PHP - linking a table to HTML and doing multiplication

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have the following php code that generates a 10X10 [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzIrq.jpg):

```
<?php
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
    echo "<tr> \n";
    for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) { 
       $a = "$row * $col";
       echo "<td><a href = '$a'>$a</a></td> \n";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

1. How to recreate this table in HTML, such that links will work?
2. Every field in a table needs to do a multiplication, e.g. field '5*6' gives result '30'. How to write a php class that will do this operation? So, for `row*column`, return variable `result`.

Comment: When a user clicks the link, is it supposed to show the result in the same cell?  This looks suspiciously like a homework question to me!

Comment: Not in the same cell. And this is not a homework. I am doing a test for a job.

Comment: Check my answer i hope it helps. You had a small bug while trying to do the math inside your for.

Comment: You have spaces in `href = '$a'`, it should be `href='$a'`. But I have no idea what should be `$a` in your case. Do you have any idea how/where are you going to display your result?

Comment: @barbsan,The result should be displayed after you click on the link, so in another web page.

Comment: So, for 5*6 do you need `href='5*6'` or `href='30'`? Or do you expect us to write whole logic for creating subpages for you so that you could get that job?

Comment: For what i understand, you want user to click on column 5*6 and in the other page you want to display result like. `your result for 5*6 is 30.` Right?

Comment: @Yogendrasinh, Yes

Comment: @@Yogendrasinh, Actually, the result should be displayed on the same page, but not in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Calculator.php

```
<?php
Class Calculator {

    public function calculate($row, $col){
        return $result = $row * $col;
    }
}
```

Change index.php as follow.

```
<?php include_once('Calculator.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="<?php if( (isset($_GET['col']) && $_GET['row'])){ echo Calculator::calculate($_GET['row'],$_GET['col']); } ?>">
    </div>
    <?php
    echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
    for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
        echo "<tr> \n";
        for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) { 
           $a = "$row * $col";
           echo "<td><a href=?row=$row&col=$col>".$a;
           //if( (isset($_GET['col']) && $_GET['row'] && $row==$_GET['row'] && $col==$_GET['col'])){ echo Calculator::calculate($row,$col); }else{ echo $a ;}
           echo "</a></td> \n";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = $row * $col;
```

Just remove the double quotes so it will multiple the numbers and not consider it a string.

[image: output is :]

Comment: But I don't need that as a table. I need my table with 'record*column' fields and results are separated from table.